# java - @Aspect value attribute - Prototype scoped aspect bean

Tags: java, spring-aop

I am trying to create Aspect using Spring AOP and AspectJ.

```
@Aspect(value = "perthis(execution(* x.y.z.command.Command.execute()))")
public class CommandAdvice {

     // Advices....
}
```

The Javadoc for the 'value attibute says:-

```
Per clause expression, defaults to singleton aspect.
Valid values are "" (singleton), "perthis(...)", etc
```

Everything works file without specifying the 'value' attribute in @Aspect annotation.

Using the above perthis setting resulted in following exception:-

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bean with name 'commandAspect' is a singleton, but aspect instantiation model is not singleton.
```

So I tried changing scope of advice bean to prototype:-

```
<bean id="commandAspect" class="x.y.z.command.CommandAdvice" **scope="prototype"**
    factory-method="aspectOf" />
```

This resulted in :-

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set x.y.z.command.Command field x.y.z.test.CommandTest.command to sun.proxy.$Proxy30
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:63)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:657)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
```

My requirement is to create 'prototype' scoped Aspect bean.

- Is prototype Aspect bean advisable? What are Pros and Cons in multi-threaded environment?
- How to do it using that 'value' attribute?

Comment: How are you trying to compile the code? Which compiler are you using? **What** compiler error are you getting? Do you have the appropriate aspect jar on the classpath? What version is it?

Comment: Java 6 compiler.  Using STS 3.2 for developing/compiling.
Its a Maven project and I have dependencies for Spring 2.5.6 , AspectJ. Edited my question to add the compiler error.

Comment: What exactly is inside the `perthis` parentheses? Is it a literal `...`, or did you remove the actual expression?

Comment: ... is indication that it should have a 'execution(* something.method())  like expression.